# Mvvm Light and Visual C# Express?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, visual-studio-express

Does MVVM Light work with Visual C# Express? Can't seem to get any of the templates showing up.

Comment: What project template not show up, Silverlight or WPF?

Comment: everything. Even in the installation it doesn't pick up the visual c# express isntalation

Comment: I just update my answer, please try to install project template again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, I do not support Visual C# express for MVVM Light templates. I only support express editions for the Windows Phone and for Windows 8 (Visual Studio 11 for WinRT).

I will consider supporting Visual C# express in a further revision of the installer. Unfortunately supporting new versions of Visual Studio is quite a lot of work to update the MSI...

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy to take the templates and move them to the personal template directory and they appear in visual studio 2010 express.

But I can't find the WPF4 dll. In GalaSoft binary dir, there's Silverlight 3/4/5 and WP7/WP71, but no WPF.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43068) Codeplex pages, it should. Did you explicitly follow the installation instructions given on this page?

Answer (score 0):

MVVMLight is just MVVM framework. It has nothing to do with project template in Visual Studio. I think your problem is Visual Studio hasn't installed correctly.

**Update:**
In case WPF project template not show up, run `VCSExpress.exe /InstallVSTemplates` at your installation path, e.g. `$\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VCSExpress.exe /InstallVSTemplates`

Comment: Actually, MVVM Light installs project templates on supported editions of Visual Studio and Blend.