# MVVM-Light templates don't appear in VS2010-Express

Tags: mvvm-light

I have just installed MVVM-LightV4 beta 1/4.0.2.19 on XP SP3 with VS2010-Express. No MVVM-Light project templates appear when I create a new project. I looked at [Mvvm Light and Visual C# Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7776946/mvvm-light-and-visual-c-sharp-express) but that didn't help.
Does this version of MVVM-Light not work with VS2010-express?
Any suggestions?
PS This does seem to be a known problem - see http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7559?ProjectName=mvvmlight

Comment: Hi, I posted on another thread to ask you to contact me per email. I will help you work through the installer's issues. Cheers, Laurent